# Script not working as expected via Windows 10 Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduler

I have a mapped drive (Z:) on my laptop. I am using the Unix2Dos util to format text files on that mapped drive through the use of a batch file. When I run the script from command line it works as expected, but when it runs in scheduler it never goes out to the mapped drive. It basically just runs and executes within the directory where the batch file resides.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
FOR %%f IN (Z:\Input\*.txt) DO C:\utils\scripts\uddu\UNIX2DOS %%f
```

Needless to say I am not sure why.

Comment: when you run a scheduled task, there simply *is no* mapped drive. You have to map it within your script or use an UNC path (`\\server\sharedFolder`)

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried that too but had the same results.:

@ECHO OFF
PUSHD 'path to location of file'
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO C:\utils\scripts\uddu\UNIX2DOS %%f
POPD

Again, when I ran it from command line it worked as a charm, but no using scheduler.

Comment: @rickman you should be using the standard double quotes, not a single apostrophe. `PUSHD "\\server\share"`. Other than that are you sure the user the scheduled task is running as has permissions to that server share?

Comment: @Squashman -  So I had it to run regardless if my user was logged in or not, which I guess was using some type of generic user with limited permissions. Changed it to run only when my user was logged in and totally worked. Thx you for suggesting permissions.